# sed/awk - removing text between delimiters

Tags: sed, awk, delimiter

How would I remove all text between certain delimiters.

example:

```
hello;you;are;nice
```

returns:

```
hello;you;nice
```

in sed, i know how to remove text before the first delimiter and after the last, but not sure otherwise...

thanks as always to everyone.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Between which delimiters? 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: yes, sorry - for example between the second and third.

Answer (score 2):

What about using cut -

```
cut -d; -f2-3
```

Answer (score 2):

It is quite straigthforward with `sed`

```
sed "s/\w*;//3"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\; -v OFS=";" '{print $1,$2,$4}' file
```